# Legend not showing properly in LayerList

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend, feature-layer

In my web app using ArcGIS API for Javascript 4.18, I am bringing in 3 layers served from a mapServer REST Service using `MapImageLayer.` I also have a `LayerList` widget to display these layers. My problem is that while the layer display correctly, the legend doesn't show up in the collapsed sublayer. I does show up in the overall collapsed menu for the entire layer, but that's not where I want it. I want each sublayer to have its own legend next to it:
[image]

My `MapImage Layer` is configured as below:

```
var Layers_right = new MapImageLayer({
    url: mapServer,
    Title: "Layers",
    sublayers: [
        {
            title: "Streamline",
            id: 0,
            visible: true
        }, {
            title: "Effective Flood Hazard Area",
            id: 1,
            visible: true
        }, {
            title: "Depth 10%",
            id: 9,
            visible: false
        }
    ]
});
```

My `layerList` is configured as below:

```
 var layerList_right = new LayerList({
        view: popupView2,
        listItemCreatedFunction: function (event) {
            const item = event.item;
            if (item.layer.type !== "group") {
                // don't show legend twice
                item.panel = {
                    content: "legend",
                    open: false
                };
            }
        }
```

What do I have configured incorrectly here? How can I get the legend to show up when I click the collapse menu next to the sublayer?

Comment: Hi, it seems like a normal behavior of the API and that your sublayer has no legend. Have you tried to add the Legend widget to your app and see what it shows for this sublayer ? https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Legend.html

Comment: Yes, the legend widget was added to the app (the client wants both a standalone legend widget (open on default) and the legend showing on each individual sublayer (but not at the top) in the layerList). The standalone Legend widget displays the symbology for the sublayers correctly.

Comment: Is it malfunctionning only for sublayer depth 10% or equally for all sublayers ?

Comment: All of them, or rather non of the sublayers are displaying the legend in the layerlist widget.

Comment: I tried your code on a mapImageLayer. The legend shows for the group but not for individual Layers as in your case. For sublayers, I tried logging "listItem.layer.type" and I got "undefined', is it the same for you ?

Comment: Yep. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've already found another solution or given up on this task by now, but for future reference this has been a known issue in the 4.x api for quite a while. The only solution I've come across is to build your own legend dynamically for each of the sublayers. I'm still hopeful that this will be included into the Layer List widget at some point.

This [link](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-api-for-javascript-questions/display-layerlist-with-legend-using-a/td-p/545006) gives some good options for getting started, but you may need to customize it a little for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @topShotta - I appreciate you taking the time to post an answer. I ended up just removing the legend under the layer list and just using the actual legend widget on the opposite side. Thanks for the info.